# How do I SSH into a Linux server from a Linux bastion host?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

The scenario is like this:

```
Windows workstation -> Linux bastion host -> Linux server
```

From my Windows workstation I use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) to SSH into the Linux bastion host from which I then SSH into the Linux server.

Question is, how do I do that when the authentication between the bastion host and Linux server is ppk authentication and I do not wish to store the ppk key for the Linux server on my bastion host?

Answer (score 2):

This is usually approached by means of [Using agent forwarding](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.62/htmldoc/Chapter9.html#pageant-forward):

> Agent forwarding is a mechanism that allows applications on your SSH
>   server machine to talk to the agent on your client machine.

That is, assuming you are [Using Pageant for authentication](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.62/htmldoc/Chapter9.html#pageant) in the first place, you simply need to set the option to *‘Allow agent forwarding’* when starting your SSH session and you should be good to go, i.e. using `ssh` on the bastion host will automatically attempt to retrieve a key from your local Pageant process.

- Obviously there are a few environmental constraints, most notably that *at present, agent forwarding in SSH-2 is only available when your SSH server is OpenSSH*, but accordingly I haven't had any problems using it with most regular [Amazon EC2 AMIs](https://aws.amazon.com/amis), e.g. the official Ubuntu ones.